# How can I display number of movies and the number of tv shows produced in 5 select countries from my data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to display the number of movies and the number of tv shows produced in 5 select countries (of my dataframe).

I have managed with just one (in this case the US)

```
netflix_df.loc[netflix_df['country'] == 'United States']['type'].value_counts().head(5)
```

returns this:

Movie      2058
TV Show     760

However, I don't know how I can display the same with 4 other select countries without writing 4 other different lines. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean select countries that you are giving? Then something like this would work:

```
netflix_df.loc[netflix_df['country'].isin(['United States', 'Germany', 'Argentina', 'Belgium'])]['type'].value_counts().head(5)
```

Comment: I get this error now : KeyError: "None of [Index([ 'United States',\n 'Pakistan',\n 'United States',\n 'India'],\n dtype='object', length=8807)] are in the [index]"

Comment: Maybe there is a bracket wrong? Even when I enter countries that do not exist in the dataframe then the resulting dataframe will just be empty.

Comment: yes I found it, netflix_df.loc[netflix_df['country'].isin(['United States','Japan','India','United Kingdom','South Korea'])]['type'].value_counts()